# Any Rx operator which could FlatMap and return both the output

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to know if there's an appropriate RxJava operator for my use-case. I have the below two methods. These are retrofit interfaces.

```
fun getSources(): Single<Sources>
fun getTopHeadlines(sourceCsv: String): Single<TopHeadlines>
```

Currently I'm doing this

```
getSources()
    .map { sources -> 
        // convert the sources list to a csv of string 
    }
    .flatMap { sourcesCsv
        getTopHeadlines(sourcesCsv)
    }
    .subsribe {topHeadlines, error -> }
```

This works well and good, if my objective is to get the top headlines. But what I'm instead trying to get is both the sources as well as top headlines while subscribing to it? Is there any operator that I'm not aware off or is there any other way of doing the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `zip()` method to do this. zip waits for both items then emits the required value. you can use it like this

```
getSources()
    .map { sources -> 
        // convert the sources list to a csv of string 
    }
    .flatMap { sourcesCsv ->
        Single.zip(
            Single.just(sourcesCsv),
            getTopHeadlines(sourcesCsv),
            BiFunction { t1, t2 -> Pair(t1, t2) }
        )
    }
```

then when you subscribe to this you have both values as a Pair. you can make an extension function for it and make you life easier:

```
fun <T, V> Single<T>.zipWithValue(value: V) = Single.zip(
    Single.just(value),
    this,
    { t1, t2 -> Pair(t1, t2) }
)
```

and inside your `flatMap` you can do `getTopHeadlines(sourcesCsv).zipWithValue(sourcesCsv)`. the same could be done for `Maybe`, and for `Flowabale` you can use `combineLatest()` method.

Comment: After perusing several articles for a while, I can say that this is the best solution for the problem. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to mohsens answer:

You do not need to zip it. Just use another `map` operator inside the `flatMap` and combine both values to a `Pair`, just as I did in this example:

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class So65640603 {
    @Test
    fun `65640603`() {
        getSources()
            .flatMap { source -> getTopHeadlines(source).map { headLines -> source to headLines } }
            .test()
            .assertValue("v1" to 42)
    }
}

fun getSources(): Single<String> {
    return Single.just("v1")
}

fun getTopHeadlines(sourceCsv: String): Single<Int> {
    return Single.just(42)
}
```